# Use special characters like 'ß' or space in URL

Tags: android, url, special-characters

I get an Address via Geocode which looks like this e.g.: "Downing Street, London" and I build an URL String with this address String and other parameters.

This is how i build the url string:

```
String url = "http://www.friendlyride.at/...?...&enterstring="+enterstring+"&enterlng="+enterLng+"&enterlat="+enterLat+"&exitstring="+exitstring+"&exitlng="+exitLng+"&exitlat="+exitLat+"&info="+infoinput;
```

enterstring = "Downing Street, London"

Now when I log the URL (which I then call in a JSON AsyncTask with an HTTPDataHandler), the URL is a link (blue) until an 'ß', space or ',' is in the String.

This is the URL in the Android Monitor (Log.d):

http://www.friendlyride.at/...?...&enterstring=Downing Street, London&enterlng=-0.1272206&enterlat=51.5032077&exitstring=Abbey Rd,                                                      London&exitlng=-0.1830032&exitlat=51.5367909&info=info

The whole url should be a link (here it breaks at a space). If I enter the Url manually in the browser, it works with spaces and everything.
 So how can i use the whole string as url?

If you need any code, please tell me, I'm not sure what code I should include. :)

Comment: "This is how i build the url string" -- you may wish to switch to some code that will automatically build up the string from parts, encoding the needed parts, like `Uri.Builder`. "So how can i use the whole string as url?" -- you need to [URL-encode the parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url needs to be encoded to be valid.

For that purpose and greatly improving your code quality as well, I strongly encourage you using `Uri.Builder` to build your urls :

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
       .authority("www.friendlyride.at")
       .appendQueryParameter("enterstring", enterstring)
       .appendQueryParameter("enterlng", Long.toString(enterLng))
       .appendQueryParameter("enterlat", Long.toString(enterLat));
       //Append all your other parameters
String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

This will construct a valid encoded url, like : http://www.friendlyride.at?enterstring=Downing%20Street%2C%20London&enterlng=-0.1272206&enterlat=51.5032077

Note : I do not know what the `...?...` part ment in your url, I haven't put it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it. I didn't know about the Uri.Builder :) And the ...?... is the path and some other parameters.